# Curl (7.21.2) and SMTP

Tags: c, curl, smtp, libcurl

I've managed to make my sample program in C connect to a server and issue the MAIL FROM and RCPT TO commands, but I'm stumped on how to send the DATA part of the handshake. If anyone knows how to do this a simple example would be very helpful.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

The way I found was with CURLOPT_READDATA.

Answer (score 0):

You send `DATA`, wait for an ack ([looks like 354](http://www.perturb.org/display/SMTP_Mail_Handshake.html)), and then send your mail, terminated with a line consisting of only a full-stop ('.').

E.g.:

```
>> DATA

<< ACK

>> Header1: foo
>> Header2: bar
>> Body of the email...
>> .
```

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to do it with curl. I can send everything, but that part fine.

Comment: Oh. I have absolutely no idea, sorry! Can you use the same function you're using to send individual commands / verify ACKs for 'DATA', and then just send the body? I'm reaching in the dark here...